# Autoconfigure existing HA nodes when adding new HA node

Tags: neo4j

I have an HA Neo4j cluster of 3 server nodes. I'd like to understand the best way to add an additional server node to the cluster. Based on my current knowledge:

1. Create new HA server node based on Image of current node
2. Edit config file of new server node
3. Edit config files of each existing server node
4. Restart all server nodes one at a time to pick up new config

Is there a more automatic way to add new node to my HA cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with 1.9 there is no need to change the configuration of already existing cluster member if you want to add a new instance.
Key for this is using `ha.discovery.url` as documented on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-configuration.html#_different_methods_for_participating_in_a_cluster.